# InputStreamReader reads 13 and 10 for carriage return. Why?

Tags: java, int, byte, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm using the `FileInputStream.read()` method to parse a text file in the context of a homework on the Huffman algorithm.

My text file goes like this (the numbers are just line numbers) :

> 1.
>   2.s
>   3.
>   4.

The return of the read() method is respectively:

13,115,10,10

And when I write these back in another text file with an `FileOutputStream`, the newline characters don't do a newline.

Why is the first line's newline character always 13 and the other ones 10?
Am I using the correct classes or should I use different stream readers?
Why don't the newline characters do a newline when I write them back into a file?

UPDATE!

Ok sorry about that, the reading is not a problem.

First, here is some code :

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileOut);
fos.write(115); //s
fos.write(13);  //newline
fos.write(115); //s
fos.write(10);  //newline
fos.write(10);  //newline
```

When I open the file in notepad I see :

1.ss
2.

I guess I have to do something to the int variables (or constants in this case) but I don't know what.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't do a newline"?

Comment: I mean there is no seperation between the top line and the bottom line.

Comment: can you show your code to write back to  file

Comment: And show the code you're using to read.

Comment: Notepad doesn't consider \r (CR, ASCII 13) or \n (LF, ASCII 10) to be a newline. The Windows convention is to use \r\n (CRLF, ASCII 13 followed by 10). Don't ever trust what you see in Notepad.

Answer (score 1):

Both carriage return ("\r", CR, ASCII 13) and line feed ("\n", LF, ASCII 10) are valid line endings, and are the conventions used on old Macintoshes and Unixes respectively.

Windows uses carriage return followed by linefeed ("\r\n", CRLF, ASCII 13, 10).

See Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

The person who created the text file might have used different line endings either deliberately, or accidentally by editing the file on operating systems with different line ending conventions.

If you want to read the file as lines, you might want to use a `BufferedReader` wrapping an `InputStreamReader`:

```
Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, encoding));

in.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is you ought to read this as text (for example, reading line by line with a BufferedReader), not binary.

If you print

```
"\rx\n" (or the equivalent with numbers)
```

it should indeed do a line feed, but programs like Windows Notepad will not recognize the single \n.

To analyze such cases, you probably want a hex editor.